# How to stretch vertical scroll?

Tags: html, css

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/dy3ed5px/10/) I put some simple example of standard layout (header, content with scrollable div, footer)

I stuck with css puzzle - how stretch the scroll div `div#content > div#scroll` so that it fills the page up to the footer?

```css
div#page { /* aka html */
    height          : 100%;
    width           : 100%;
 margin          : 0 auto;
    box-sizing      : border-box;
    overflow        : auto;
}

div.cleaner {
    clear : both;
}

header {
    display   : block;
    width     : 100%;
}

header > div#left_head {
    float      : left;
    width      : 50%;
    box-sizing : border-box;
    border     : dotted blue 1px;
}

header > div#right_head {
    float      : right;
    width      : 50%;
    box-sizing : border-box;
    text-align : right;
    border     : dotted blue 1px;
}

footer {
    display   : block;
    width     : 100%;
    position  : absolute;
    left      : 0px;
    bottom    : 0px;
}

footer > div#left_foot {
    float      : left;
    width      : 50%;
    box-sizing : border-box;
    border     : dotted green 1px;
}

footer > div#right_foot {
    float      : right;
    width      : 50%;
    box-sizing : border-box;
    text-align : right;
    border     : dotted green 1px;
}

/*---------------->8---------------*/

div#content {
    width  : 90%;
    margin : 0 auto;
    border : dotted black 1px;
}

div#content > div#scroll {
    height    : 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
    <header>
        <div id="left_head">
            <span>here is left header</span>
        </div>
        <div id="right_head">
            <span>here is right header</span>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div id="dummy" class="cleaner" />
    
    <div id="content">
        <div id="scroll">
            <p>scrollable content</p>
            <p>scrollable content</p>
            <p>scrollable content</p>
            <p>scrollable content</p>
            <p>scrollable content</p>
            <p>scrollable content</p>
            <p>scrollable content</p>
            <p>scrollable content</p>
            <p>scrollable content</p>
            <p>scrollable content</p>
            <p>scrollable content</p>
            <p>scrollable content</p>
            <p>scrollable content</p>
            <p>scrollable content</p>
            <p>scrollable content</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <div id="left_foot">
            <span>here is left foot</span>
        </div>
        <div id="right_foot">
            <span>here is right foot</span>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
```

In the given example I constrained the height by hard-codded value of 200px.

any ideas, comments - appreciated.

thank you!

Comment: Not sure about your fiddle link (404) - but found [this one?](http://jsfiddle.net/dy3ed5px/10/)

Comment: right.. sorry for the confusion. I edited the link.

Comment: @jbutler483
I don't get it. `overflow-x` controls browser's actions in case if content goes over horizontal borders (scroll left-right).
But I need to stretch the div vertically. I can play with `position : absolute` and set `top, left, bottom, right`. But I find it too 'rigid' - header/footer sizes can change. Also, positioning the div#content in the middle becomes problematic.

Comment: You might actually be interested in using a sticky footer (although i'm personally not a fan of them)?

Comment: @AlexLaban Sorry I think I misunderstood the question before you edited it. Please ignore my original comment. =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you need JavaScript for this, because you need to determine the distance between the bottom of `header` and the top of `footer`.

You can use [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect) for that.

```
var content= document.querySelector('div#content');
var header= document.querySelector('header');
var footer= document.querySelector('footer');

content.style.height= footer.getBoundingClientRect().top - 
                      header.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - 1 + 'px';
```

Because `header`'s children are floats, you need to add `overflow:auto` in order for `header` to have a height (and therefore a `bottom` coordinate):

```
header {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

You can then change the height in this style:

```
div#content > div#scroll {
  height    : 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

... to this:

```
div#content > div#scroll {
  height    : 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Since `content` now has a hard-coded height, you'll need to adjust it when resizing the window.  You'll see that in my fiddle:

### Fiddle

Comment: Thank you!

JS is a power! 

What I still don't quite understand is how browsers calculate height. For example, I put this example http://jsfiddle.net/laban/uwvcvzun/4/

it works fine too, except for that nasty page scroll!! Why does browser create scroll for the whole page?

Comment: In your style for `div#page > div#scrollable`, you have height 100%.  That causes `scrollable`'s height to be equal to the screen height, so it can't fit on the page along with the header and footer.  That causes the scroll bar to appear for the page.

Comment: I posted an HTML/CSS answer to a similar question today at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321418/full-height-fluid-layout-with-editable-textfield/27323667#27323667